# Display a StackLayout with objects in Binding on multiple lines

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `StackLayout` with `Binding` elements inside a `Grid` Layout.
The `stackLayout` shows a series of objects, and I would like that when it horizontally gets to the end of the screen, the objects continue to display them by wrapping, so a simple `Label`. The problem is that the objects are always displayed to me only on one line, and I cannot see them all.

[image: Example]

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout
   Grid.Row="2"
   Grid.Column="2"                                               
   BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}"
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   Orientation="Horizontal">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Grid RowSpacing="0.5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="5" Opacity="0.6" />
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding isSource}" Margin="3"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
              </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is wraping and it is provided by `FlexLayout`

Modify these properties according to your need
`Wrap` `AlignItems` `Direction` `JustifyContent` to get desired result

```
<FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemSource}" 
            Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="Start" Direction="Row" AlignItems="Start" AlignContent="Start">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <!-- Your Template -->
          </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

Another [example](https://askxammy.com/getting-started-with-flexlayout-properties-behavior/) to help you out

Answer (score 0):

stacklayout can not achieve it and you can use collectionview and set the itemsLayout to gridLayout